# dedicate 1 public IP to all devices in a subnet

Tags: cisco-asa

I have a range of 6 public IP addresses and an ASA5505

I have two subnets and 2 VLANs

1. inside network 10.0.0.0/24 VLAN 1
2. DMZ subnet 172.25.15.10/24 VLAN 40

all devices in the inside network connect through public ip 63.73.83.93 (not real IP)

all devices in the DMZ subnet connect using the same Public IP address

I know i can one to one nat to give the Servers in the DMZ public IP addresses but what i am looking for is exactly what the inside network has, all devices in VLAN 1 to share the public IP address
and all devices in DMZ subnet to share the second IP address

just to be clear, all devices in the subnet should use my second Public ip just as the inside network does

Any suggestions?

ASA version 9.3

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Servers should generally have static nat (one-to-one mapping), but some hacks exist depending on what services you provide.

You can put in front a server with the public address you wish and the other servers behind it.
 If you host for example different web servers in you DMZ, one possible solution is to forward traffic to a specific server using the website name, and if you providing different services you can forward traffic by PORT.

Comment: `Servers should generally have static nat (one-to-one mapping), but some hacks exist depending on what services you provide.`. You should remove that part. There are no finite rules when in comes to how NAT should or shouldn't be - it has to be case by case.  For example, if the servers only need to reach the internet for updates but don't need to be reachable FROM the internet, there is absolutely no need for then to have dedicated IP addresses.

Answer (score 0):

This could be done with a second router but, I suppose that's the more obvious and simple answer.

Alternatively, if you have a more advanced router/firewall with a second WAN port a rule could be made that stated traffic from DMZ goes out WAN2 and vice versa for incoming.

Also I believe a virtual IP could be added with similar rules instead of doing 1:1 NAT

If your still using a small router it might be time to upgrade? Or build something (pfsense)?